# How to set query variable into subdirectory .htaccess (301 redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How would you redirect (301?)?:

**test.com/?dep=CAR**     (the variable is dynamic, whatever comes after the=)

to a subdirectory:

**test.com/CAR/**

This is what I've got so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dep=(.*)
RewriteRule ^.* / [L,R=301]
```

I test this on a localhost (WAMP).
And the main directory is **localhost/newsite/**
(localhost/newsite/?dep=CAR)
, but I guess that shouldn't matter? Online or localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#if it has a dep param, capture the value
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)dep=([^&]+) [NC]
#and redirect to /value/
RewriteRule .* /%2/? [L,R=301]


#if there is no dep param
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !dep= [NC]
#and capture the directory and pass as a dep param
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ ?dep=$1 [L]
```

Comment: When I try this I get "http://localhost//?dep=CAR" (I've updated the op with a bit more information)

Comment: @Rob Fixed typo and added `?` to suppress the original Query String above

Comment: The url gets to the subdir but is say's "The requested URL localhost/newsite/CAR/ was not found on this server". org localhost/newsite/?dep=CAR.

Comment: maybe I should do it the other way around dir to query (on the bg)

Comment: @Rob I just added a section to process directory to query string. If you are modifying an existing site's links then you need the first rule to redirect traffic to the new format. However, you will always need the second section to write back to you application. If you application is index.php, its better to write the rule as `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?dep=$1 [L]`